# jQuery - Replace multiple characters in multiple strings with html snippets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

Trying to scan through various strings and replace all occurrences of specific characters with html snippets.

For instance - I would like to scan through the following:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>10,000 | 20,000 | 30,000</div>
    <div>10,000 |: 20,000</div>
    <div>10,000 :| 20,000</div>
</div>
```

And have it output as:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>10,000 <span class="single"></span> 20,000 <span class="single"></span> 30,000</div>
    <div>10,000 <span class="single-wide"></span> 20,000</div>
    <div>10,000 <span class="wide-single"></span> 20,000</div>
</div>
```

The following works for locating the characters and then replacing with other text, but doesn't work for multiple instances of the character in the same string, and doesn't allow inserting the html tags.

```
$('#wrapper div').text(function (i, old) {
   return old
       .replace(' | ',' single ')
       .replace(' |: ', ' single-wide ')
       .replace(' :| ', ' wide-single ');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s60v8o5x/

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **regular expression** to replace multiple string and use **html** instead of **text**

```
$('#wrapper div').html(function (i, old) {
  return old
   .replace(/ \| /g,' <span class="single"</span> ')
   .replace(/ \|: /g, ' <span class="single-wide"></span> ')
   .replace(/ :\| /g, ' <span class="wide-single"></span> ');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dscfnnf0/2/

Comment: Thanks, Christian - that's close - how can I insert the HTML <span> tags without them rendering on the front end? https://jsfiddle.net/s60v8o5x/2/

Comment: Use html instead of text, I make some changes in the code https://jsfiddle.net/dscfnnf0/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex & fiddle if it works for you [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccjgrnfw/)

```
$('#wrapper div').text(function (i, old) {
  return old
   .replace(/ \| /g,' <span class="single"></span> ')
   .replace(/ \|: /g, ' <span class="single-wide"></span> ')
   .replace(/ :\| /g, ' <span class="wide-single"></span> ');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Agam, guess using html was the difference.

Comment: I thought you asked to not render the html on frontend in the accepted answer comment. Still glad i could help :)